# When I try to save an image I get the error "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Tags: c#, bitmap, gif, save

When I run this code, on the line I commented I always get an "A generic error occurred in GDI+." run time error

```
    private void ConstructFromResourceSaveAsGif()
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(typeof(Button), "Button.bmp");

        //This line
        bmp1.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating a bitmap that type is a button??? It doesn't work since your are obtaining a button that is a bitmap

Comment: @OutlawLemur This code comes from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47591zc7.aspx

Comment: @KendallFrey But does the OP want the Bitmap to be a Button?

Comment: I got the same error when System.IO errors popped up - e.g. not creating a directory first.  So might want to make sure you have correct permissions etc.

Comment: I don't want it to be a button, I just copied the code from MSDN

Comment: So, what are you actually trying to achieve, apart from "save a gif". Throw in some more detail to help the people helping you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the code

```
private void ConstructFromResourceSaveAsGif()
{
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap("Button.bmp");

    bmp1.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
}
```

and it will still work, unless you are trying to accomplish what @DanF is saying.

**EDIT**

Here's a quick app I used to test it out:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap("C:/donut.jpg");

        bmp1.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

        Console.WriteLine("Save Success");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem with the first line, but on the second line where it saves it its still giving me the run time error

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the typeof line does too :-) For this case, it whacks the namespace of the type and the filename together, then looks for an embedded resource called that.

Comment: Yep, saw that, +1'd your answer

Answer (score 2):

> This constructor combines the namespace of the given type with the
>   string name of the resource and looks for a match in the assembly
>   manifest. For example you can pass in the Button type and Button.bmp
>   to this constructor and it will **look for a resource named
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.bmp.**

Do you have a resource named that? If not, that'll be your problem. "A generic error occured..." is GDI+'s not very friendly way of throwing its hands in the air and saying "it broke but I'm not going to tell you why"